# Postgres ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE doesn't trigger if other constraints fail

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE external_item (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  external_id TEXT UNIQUE,
  enabled BOOLEAN NOT NULL CHECK (enabled = false OR external_id IS NOT NULL)
);

INSERT INTO external_item (id, enabled, external_id)
     VALUES (1, true, 'ext_id_1');

INSERT INTO external_item (id, enabled)
     VALUES (1, true)
ON CONFLICT (id)
  DO UPDATE
        SET enabled = excluded.enabled;

--> ERROR: new row for relation "external_item" violates check constraint "external_item_check"
--> DETAIL: Failing row contains (1, null, t).
```

The query fails because it the insert doesn't pass the check constraint. Everything works fine if you omit the `CHECK` from the table definition. Is there some way to set constraint priority or something so that Postgres would resort to the `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` statement before asserting other checks?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) `on conflict` **only** deals with unique or exclusion constraints and nothing else.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with upserts alone. Perhaps a trigger is what you what ;)